# What are Functional and Conceptional specification?

Tags: terminology, specifications

In my new task, I have been asked to write specifications for a new project. Actually I have never written any specifications except few rough drafts after discussions.

I need to write specifications in two parts first conceptional specifications and following functional specification. I just wonder what will be outline for such document. It would be great if someone could give me some guidelines with explanation what these terms actually mean. Any online references or book suggestions?

Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptual specs are for describing the system you're about to build.  These specs should be readable by non-technical people (and there is a lot to know about how to write them correctly)

Functional specs are more what the engineers would use to write the system.  The functional specs are made from the conceptual specs and it's more of a detailed description of every method and such that you need to write to accomplish the end result.

Most engineers that I've worked with have hated this process, however, if done right you'll find that once you actually get to the programming phase it will go very quickly.

Comment: somewhere out there are some really great examples of both of these types of documents.  it would probably be very helpful to find one of these templates (Microsoft has them on there site somewhere)...jump start your documentation and make you look really cool when you turn in a very professional looking draft.  I've got some fires this morning to put out so I'll try to make time and find them for you later on today.

Comment: Thanks. It would be always great to see some suggestions from an experienced one. Looking forward for links.

Answer (score 0):

Functional- It's the documentation that describes the requested behavior of an engineering system. The documentation typically describes what is needed by the system user as well as requested properties of inputs and outputs